# jblas 2-d matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, 2d, multiplication, jblas

I want to compute  2d matrix-matrix multiplication using the Jblas library. But I failed every time to compute. Please help me to do this by giving an example with data.

Answer (score 0):

That should be fairly straightforward, just make sure that your matrices have the right size:

```
DoubleMatrix matA = new DoubleMatrix(2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4);
DoubleMatrix matB = new DoubleMatrix(2, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8);

DoubleMatrix res = matA.mmul(matB);
```